# Killing process in onPause()

Tags: android

I want to kill my Activity process when I pause it by answering a call or something like that
but when i try to start my app it closes instantly. Any solutions? Sample code below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

    //Things to do
}

//@Override
public void onPause() {      
    super.onPause();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Comment: try with `this.finish();` instead of `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: Still doesn work :/ Its just finishing on start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: It closes? can you put a stack trace please? what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

update your code with

```
@Override
public void onPause() {      
    super.onPause();
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: Still nothing it just closes on start ;/

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a logical scenario based on activity's lifecycle methods.